# Error Kotlin Type inference failed Expected type mismatch Map<MessageDestination, List<MessageSender>> was expected

Tags: java, kotlin, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to manipulate the structure of data so that I can pass it to this function `fun handleRequests(messages: Map<MessageDestination, List<MessageSender>>): Either<Errors.RequestError, Unit>`. But I keep getting this error: 
[syntaxerror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl0pj.png)

`Error:(27, 63) Kotlin: Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Map<MessageDestination, List<Pair<MessageSender, String>>> but Map<MessageDestination, List<MessageSender>> was expected`.

I need to transform my data into `Map<MessageDestination, List<MessageSender>>` but I don't know how to do it. Here's the code:

```
package testp.package1.handlers

import arrow.core.Either
import arrow.core.flatMap
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler

interface InterfaceService {
    fun handleRequests(messages: Map<MessageDestination, List<MessageSender>>): Either<Errors.RequestError, Unit>
}

abstract class AbstractMessageHandler(
        override val service: InterfaceService =
                ServiceImpl()) : MessageHandler<MyMessage>() {

    abstract val emailType: ServiceImpl.Companion.EmailType
    override val emailParser: IMessageParser<MyMessage> = M2MessageParser()

    override fun handle(event: List<String>): Either<Errors.RequestError, Pair<List<Errors.RequestError>, Int>> =
            emailParser.parseEmails(event)
                    .map { (error, messages) ->
                        error to messages.map { myMessage ->
                            MessageSender(message = myMessage.environment) to myMessage.emailAdrress
                        }
                    }
                    .flatMap { (errors: List<Errors.RequestError>, emailMesssages: List<Pair<MessageSender, String>>) ->
                        service.handleRequests(emailMesssages.groupBy { MessageDestination(it.second) }).map {
                            Pair(errors, emailMesssages.size)
                        }
                    }
}

data class MessageDestination(val emailAddress: String)
data class MyMessage(val environment: String, val emailAdrress: String, val phoneId: String)
data class MessageSender(val message: String)


class ServiceImpl : InterfaceService {
    override fun handleRequests(messages: Map<MessageDestination, List<MessageSender>>): Either<Errors.RequestError, Unit> {
        TODO("logic goes her")
    }
    companion object {
        enum class EmailType {
            M1, M2
        }
    }
}

object Errors {
    interface RequestError {
        val message: String
    }
    data class UnexpectedError(override val message: String) : RequestError
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:**
You want to transform values that are grouped in list, so:

```
emailMesssages.groupBy( 
    { MessageDestination(it.second) },
    { it.first }
)
```

**Long version:**

Ok, so you start with:
`emailMesssages: List<Pair<MessageSender, String>>`
and you want to transform it to type `Map<MessageDestination, List<MessageSender>>`

You are trying to achieve that with `emailMesssages.groupBy { MessageDestination(it.second) }`. What `groupBy` does it groups items from the list by key that you specified. What's important is that it combines all items (in this case all `Pair`s) for one key **into the list**.

So if you have (sample from [official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html)):

```
val words = listOf("a", "abc", "ab", "def", "bc")
val byLength = words.groupBy { it.length }
```

then byLength is:

```
1 -> listOf("a")
2 -> listOf("ab", "bc")
3 -> listOf("abc", "def")
```

That explains why you have type `Map<MessageDestination, List<Pair<MessageSender, String>>>` instead of `Map<MessageDestination, List<MessageSender>>`.

What you want to do is **not to group items from the list**, you want to **group transformed values from items of the list**.

Basically what you want is another variant of ['groupBy'](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) with keySelector AND valueTransform:

```
inline fun <T, K, V> Array<out T>.groupBy(
    keySelector: (T) -> K,
    valueTransform: (T) -> V
): Map<K, List<V>> (source)`
```

in your case, that would look like this:

```
emailMesssages.groupBy( 
    { MessageDestination(it.second) },
    { it.first }
)
```